# Dispay IST Time reading ToUniversalTime() from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, timezone

I am storing the user submitted post by converting to **ToUniversalTime()** in database MYSQL using C# language.

```
 BLLContext bll=new BLLContext();
 bll.DatePosted = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
 BLLContextRepo repo=new BLLContextReop();
 repo.SubmitContext(bll);
```

When I tried to retrieve it using **ToLocalTime()** it is showing the server's local time ( it is in United States). But I want to show Indian Standard time (IST).
Actual Code which is not showing Indian Standard Time

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0: MMM d, yyyy "+"@"+" hh:mm tt}",((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DateUpdated")).ToLocalTime()) %>' />
```

Is there something like

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0: MMM d, yyyy "+"@"+" hh:mm tt}",((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DateUpdated")).ToLocalTime("Indian Standard Time")) %>' />
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert the `DateTime` using the relevant `TimeZoneInfo`. For example:

```
TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Indian Standard Time");
DateTime indian = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(originalDateTime, zone);
```

Alternatively, you might want to look at the date/time API I'm writing, [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) which I'd like to think makes all of this a bit clearer, by separating out the idea of a "local" date/time (no time zone) from one where you know the zone, from one where you just know the offset from UTC.

Comment: Does Noda Time supports Medium trust enviornment?

Comment: @hungrycoder: Not sure - I don't know enough about the various requirements of that to say. It doesn't do anything particularly security-sensitive though - it reads resources, generally from its own assembly, and it *can* use `TimeZoneInfo` if you want it to. You could at least give it a try :)

Comment: you mentioned "zone.ConvertTimeFromUtc(originalDateTime, zone);"
both are zone only it is throwing error
Member 'System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(System.DateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead